# Guava issue when starting Asterisk-Java

Tags: java, maven, guava, asterisk

I'm trying to compile a project and it uses guava. The project is Asterisk-Java (https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java) and when I'm trying to run the .jar with the command `java -cp asterisk-java.jar org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer`, the following error appear :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter at org.asteriskjava.lock.Lockable.<init>(Lockable.java:23) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AbstractMappingStrategy.<init>(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:38) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.<init>(ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.java:93) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.<init>(ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.java:67) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.<init>(ResourceBundleMappingStrategy.java:57) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer.<init>(DefaultAgiServer.java:158) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer.<init>(DefaultAgiServer.java:136) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer.<init>(DefaultAgiServer.java:76) at org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer.main(DefaultAgiServer.java:394) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ... 9 more`

Here's the dependencies used that make crash:
 `<dependency> <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> <artifactId>guava</artifactId> <version>32.0.1-jre</version> </dependency>`

I tryied to change the guava version in pom.xml but it still not working :/

I tryied to change guava version to make the rate limiter work but nothing changed.

Comment: Looks like you should add all your dependencies to the classpath.

Comment: Exactly. Make sure that you either build a single jar with all dependencies included, or that you add all relevant dependency/library jars to the classpath when running your application.

Comment: So, even if asterisk-java should work out of the box, I have to download additional software and ad it to java cp ?

Comment: Ok you were right my bad, I had to download guava jre and add it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: Indeed, to fix this issues, I had to download the guava .jar (jre) (here: https://github.com/google/guava/releases) and add it in the cp by running this command : `java -cp asterisk-java.jar:guava-32.1.1-jre.jar org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer`

And it worked perfeclty. Thanks to helpers.